# Assigning a constant value to interval of records in pyspark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame like below in `pyspark`

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(1,'Y'),
(2,'Y'),
(3,'N'),
(4,'N'),
(5,'N'),
(6,'Y'),
(7,'N')
],
('id', 'status')
)


df.show()

+---+------+
| id|status|
+---+------+
|  1|     Y|
|  2|     Y|
|  3|     N|
|  4|     N|
|  5|     N|
|  6|     Y|
|  7|     N|
+---+------+
```

Now I want to create a new column `pack` in the data frame by assigning the same value for group of records. For example two records is a group

The values should start from `0`

Expected result:

```
+---+------+----+
| id|status|pack|
+---+------+----+
|  1|     Y|   0|
|  2|     Y|   0|
|  3|     N|   1|
|  4|     N|   1|
|  5|     N|   2|
|  6|     Y|   2|
|  7|     N|   3|
+---+------+----+
```

I applied the `row_number` function like below

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df1 = df.withColumn( "pack", f.round(f.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(f.lit(None)))/2).cast('int') )

df1.show()
+---+------+----+
| id|status|pack|
+---+------+----+
|  1|     Y|   1|
|  2|     Y|   1|
|  3|     N|   2|
|  4|     N|   2|
|  5|     N|   3|
|  6|     Y|   3|
|  7|     N|   4|
+---+------+----+
```

Even though the answer is similar to what I want the values are starting from `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: your dataframe in code s different from the displayed one check index 2 has N but in the show its has Y, why?

Comment: @Yefet Corrected it now

Comment: does simple -1 solve your issue? check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create data frame 
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(1,'Y'),
(2,'Y'),
(3,'N'),
(4,'N'),
(5,'N'),
(6,'Y'),
(7,'N')
],
('id', 'status')
)


df.show()

+---+------+
| id|status|
+---+------+
|  1|     Y|
|  2|     Y|
|  3|     N|
|  4|     N|
|  5|     N|
|  6|     Y|
|  7|     N|
+---+------+

# necessary imports
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

# apply ceil function and -1
df1 = df.withColumn( "pack", f.ceil(f.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(f.lit(None)))/2).cast('int') - 1)
```

Output

```
+---+------+----+
| id|status|pack|
+---+------+----+
|  1|     Y|   0|
|  2|     Y|   0|
|  3|     N|   1|
|  4|     N|   1|
|  5|     N|   2|
|  6|     Y|   2|
|  7|     N|   3|
+---+------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change how you create the row_number. To guarantee that your data will be sorted in the same way as your input, change to `f.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(f.monotonically_increasing_id()))` instead.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'Y'),
     (2, 'Y'),
     (3, 'N'),
     (4, 'N'),
     (5, 'N'),
     (6, 'Y'),
     (7, 'N'),
     (10, 'Y'),
     (11, 'N')
     ], ('id', 'status'))

df = (df
      .withColumn('row_number', f.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(f.monotonically_increasing_id())))
      .withColumn('increase', ((f.col('row_number') > f.lit(2)) &
                               (f.col('row_number') % f.lit(2) == f.lit(1))).cast('Int'))
      .withColumn('pack', f.sum('increase').over(Window.orderBy('row_number')))
      .drop('row_number', 'increase'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output

```
+---+------+----+
|id |status|pack|
+---+------+----+
|1  |Y     |0   |
|2  |Y     |0   |
|3  |N     |1   |
|4  |N     |1   |
|5  |N     |2   |
|6  |Y     |2   |
|7  |N     |3   |
|10 |Y     |3   |
|11 |N     |4   |
+---+------+----+
```

Comment: Your answer works when I divide by `2` but when I divide the say `10` then the result is not as per expected output

Comment: @nmr I did a fix, check it again

Comment: Your answer works now. But user12345 answer is simple